# There is a SQL syntax error while using JDBC to connect to MySQL which says the table doesn't exist. (But the Table Exists))

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc, syntax

I am able to connect to the data base but face the exception while executing the preparedStatement to insert values. I can access the table using the MySQL table using the workbench and also insert values from there. The spelling for the table is correct.

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO source_domain_english_OY2_Jul2014(filename, seed, words, frequency, type, after_before) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
.
.
.
.

preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

I have posted the stack trace below

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'm_r.source_domain_english_OY2_Jul2014' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
    at edu.albany.ils.remnd.balancedcorpus.english.GramsSearch.readPatterns(GramsSearch.java:948)
    at edu.albany.ils.remnd.balancedcorpus.english.GramsSearch.main(GramsSearch.java:45)
```

Comment: are you sure you're using the `m_r` database in both cases?

Comment: Did you try outputting the query in the output window like the following `System.out.println("Checking Prepared Statement:"+preparedStatement);` and then tried running in MySQL workbench to see if you are getting errors or not?

Comment: Agree check if the schema(user) is same for both

Comment: almost certainly the m_r is the difference...

Comment: Yes, I am using the same database m_r. 
String dbName = "m_r";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL.concat(dbName), databaseUser, databasePassword);

Comment: @John I tried what you said. It executed fine in the work bench. I just had to use the semicolon at the end.

Comment: @Vwin I use root in the code. It will not allow me to access the database if use the one I use in the workbench.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your MySQL DB is running in a Linux/Unix OS, where table names are case sensitive. You refer to the table as `source_domain_english_OY2_Jul2014` in your code, but you probably had some lower/upper case differences between this name and the name you used in the script the created the table.

Comment: Yeah, I am using Ubuntu. I created the table based on a different table
(create table2 like table1;)

Comment: @user3645570 The question is whether you are sure table2 was exactly `source_domain_english_OY2_Jul2014` in your create command, or perhaps it was slightly different, such as `Source_domain_english_OY2_Jul2014`.

Comment: I copied and pasted from there, so it's the same. I double-checked it. Could it be because I am using root user in the code and a different username in the workbench(access is denied if I use that username in the code)